# Text not visible until click on the text field in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have add a text for UITextfield by programatically after get the response from the external server. But the text not displaying until I click on the textfield. This is the code:

```
 if  let postcodeVal  = dictionary["postcode"]{

                            println("postcode  \(postcodeVal)")

                           self.postcode.text = postcodeVal as String

                       }
```

This textfield is not editable.(Remove the tick of user interaction enabled)

Can anyone help me to understand, why it is not displaying straight away before click on it?

Comment: have you tried to display with main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request to the external server is running on a background thread. Changes on the user interface always have to be done on the main thread.

In the completion handler of your server request you need to dispatch the update of the textfield to the main thread like so:

```
... {
    // completion handler of the server request

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.postcode.text = postcodeVal as String
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using older Xcode version. I used dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() { }. But you drive me to correct path. Thanks.